# How do I get the raw HTML in angularjs using the $http directive?

Tags: angularjs

I'm currently using `$http.get` to retrieve the data from the backend. The data received is actually in HTML format; however, it comes back escaped with \t\n and all the white spaces. If I were to perform the same `$.get` request using jQuery, the data that comes back comes unescaped. Anyway how I can use get the raw unescaped HTML? I've tried `$sce.trustAsHtml` with no avail.

Comment: Then use jQuery. But seriously, is there a reason that you need to use `$http.get`?

Comment: I'm trying to not use jQuery at all and use angularjs library so I don't have to load in both.

Comment: Are you retrieving an html file or html as text from the server?

Comment: as text from the server

Answer (score 11):

I don't know how you are getting the response, because you have not shared any code.

How are you getting the data?

I use `$http` to get raw HTML templates without any issue:

```
$http.get('url').then(function(response) {
    var raw_html = response.data;
});
```

Comment: for some odd reason, i get escaped HTML as a response regardless if I use $sce or not.

Comment: Maybe it is coming escaped from the server... can you inspect what is coming from the server? (Using Chrome developer tools, Firebug, or other tool...)

Comment: @AniketSinha: None, actually. I am used to code in PHP. Just this. I will remove the `$`.

Answer (score 9):

add `ngSanitize`

inject `$sce` and use

```
$scope.rawHtml = $sce.trustAsHtml(html)
<div ng-bind-html="rawHtml"> <div>
```